# Creating a dynamic points averaging script

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm the kind of person that's happy to sit and use trial and error over an extended period to try and work something out. I am however totally stuck and thought perhaps someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I am trying to create a script that will allow for 1-6 players to be assigned a number of objects each of which has a specific points value.

The script needs to average out the number of points each player is awarded.

It needs to be able to have a new set of objects added that it will then distribute based on the accrued number of points already gained and try and distribute them to keep the total as equal as possible.

[TL;DR bit]

Let's say there are 6 players.

In round one 6 boxes are "won": two big boxes @ "1000pts", two medium @ "500pts" and two small @ "250pts".

The script would obviously have to award the boxes one to each player.

```
p1 1000 p2 1000 p3 500 p4 500 p5 250 p6 250
```

Let's say the same amount of boxes are won in round two. The script is going to have to calculate who gets what to keep the scores as close as possible.

```
p1 250 p2 250 p3 500 p4 500 p5 1000 p6 1000
```

would give totals of

```
p1 1250 ps 1250 p3 1000 p4 1000 p5 1250 p6 1250
```

and so on for several rounds.

Basically it needs to work out each round how to award the points whilst keeping the total points for each player as close as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the concept of this is giving me a headache in trying to work out what the best approach is let alone the actual code itself!

Comment: It would help to share some of your thoughts thus far.

Comment: Will (should) each player get exactly one box each round? This would imply that there are the same number of boxes awarded each round as there are players and that, even if it would be better to assign 2 boxes to 1 player to even out this scores, this cannot be done.

Comment: any chance you accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

At each step in each round always give the box with the highest value to the player with the lowest current wealth. If, at any time, there are players tied on wealth, choose one at random.

You may or may not want to allocate more than one box to the same player in any one round, that's up to you.

Unless you know what boxes are coming next, or are planning to redistribute boxes from earlier rounds in later rounds, I don't think you can beat this simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pretty simple solution that should solve your problem, in pseudo-pseudo code:

1 first assignemnent of "boxes" as you want, maybe random

2 order players depending of the total value earned

3 assign new "boxes" from the lowest value to the highest value, starting from the player with biggest score point.

4 goto 2

Using your convention, this will end in:

1° round -------------------
p1 1000 p2 1000 p3 500 p4 500 p5 250 p6 250

2° round -------------------
p1 1250 p2 1250 pr 1000 p4 1000 p5 1250 p6 1250

the new player order become:
p1 1250 p2 1250 p5 p1250 p6 1250 p3 1000 p4 1000

and so, applying algorithm agian:
p1 1500 p2 1500 p5 1750 p6 1750 p3 2000 p4 2000

3° round
the new player order become:
p3 2000 p4 2000 p5 1750 p6 1750 p1 1500 p2 1500

and so, applying algorithm again:
p3 2250 p4 2250 p5 2250 p6 2250 p1 2500 p2 2500

..it seems it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you must always assign the boxes at random, then you can assign a probability to each person, similar to a draft lottery (if you are a sports fan).  This probability is used to see who gets the next highest valued prize.

For example:

```
Let W(i) be the current wealth for person i

Let T=W(1) + W(i) + ... + W(n)

Let P(i) = W(i) / T
```

Each `P(i)` is then the probability that person `i` will get the next lowest prize.  If you sum up all `P(i)`, it equals 1, so spread them out over the interval `(0-1)`.  Then use a random number generator to get a number between `0` and `1`.  Who ever's interval it falls in (most likely the person with the most wealth), then that person gets the lowest prize.

Recalculate `T` and `P()` with the remaining people to determine the probability for the next lower prize until all the prizes are awarded.

You can use different weights to force them closer.

Comment: hmmmmm, it seems i was thinking way too hard on this one and passed over the simplest solution. there may be more boxes in one round than players so perhaps i need to make this happen in real time so it recalculates after each individual box. thanks very much for the replies i think this will set me on the right track here !